# Fancy client-side form validation in ASP.net MVC2

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, jquery-validate

It appears that the jQuery-based version of ASP.NET MVC2 form validation didn't make it into the final release. This is a bit unfortunate.

First off, I can't figure out whether the version that did make it into the final release has an extension point - akin to an "onvalidate" event to which I can attach my own code... For instance, I would like to be able to animate the validation messages with jQuery-UI.

Secondly, I'm wondering if the jQuery validation they have in Futures is good enough for real-world use. Has anyone had any success with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the current MVC2 implementation has extension points for hooking in your own custom validation. See this post [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/19/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx) for an example.